# How to rosservice call with arrays

Tags: ros, rosservice, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS electric.

I have an srv that contains 2 arrays of int32[]
rosmake functions correctly and the service is listed.

However when I try to call the service I cannot get it to accept the arrays.

Could someone please give me an example of the syntax for the rosservice call command?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45190/how-to-rosservice-call-with-arrays/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-05**:
Which programming language would you prefer? C++, Python, Lisp or the command line syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you mean the command line syntax it would be something like

```
rosservice call /service_name [first_array_items_seperated_by_comma] [1.,2.,3.]
```

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine
might be also a good starting point to look at.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosservice provides all this information as well.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) with karma: 237 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2